# Displaying the set date using Calendar..the output is off. I do not know why

Tags: java

I do not understand why the output to the date that I have set (2013, 01, 21) gets displayed as:
Thu Feb 21 23:05:18 GMT2013.  Instead of January, the output here is Feb??

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class date {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    myCal.set(2013,01,21);
    Date bestBeforeDate = myCal.getTime();
    System.out.println(bestBeforeDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because months are ranged 0-11 in Java, 0 being January, 1 being February, ...

[Calendar javadocs for `MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH):

> The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

Comment: Workaround is to use constants that name each month, [November](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#NOVEMBER) etc. Even better, use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead of java.util.Date/Calendar.